# How to change odom parameter?

Tags: ros, turtlebot-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My turtlebot doesn't face the wall, how can i increase or decrease the odom parameter ?

> If the TurtleBot does not successfully
> return to facing the wall before
> executing the next rotation the data
> will be incorrect. This can be caused
> by too big of an error in the existing
> parameters. If it under rotates,
> increase the odom parameter and retry.
> If it over rotates, lower the

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37119/how-to-change-odom-parameter?/) by [Abtin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2687/abtin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_calibration/Tutorials/Calibrate%20Odometry%20and%20Gyro#Results) not sufficient to do the job?

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0